# cabal install MissingPy can’t find Data.HashTable

Tags: haskell, cabal

I tried to install MissingPy, but it failed with

```
on the commandline: Warning:
 -XOverlappingInstances is deprecated: instead use per-instance pragmas     OVERLAPPING/OVERLAPPABLE/OVERLAPS

src/Database/AnyDBM.hs:44:8:
    Could not find module ‘Data.HashTable’
 Perhaps you meant
   Data.Hashable (needs flag -package-key     hashable->1.2.5.0@hasha_Evd2cSGupW8AJnHTBSvXg8)
      Data.HashTable.IO (needs flag -package-key     hashtables->1.2.1.0@hasht_EuNk8qBpsPjAV2dYmonrJi)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
anydbm-1.0.7 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Somewhere I found, Data.HashTable is deprecated. There’s still documentation on hackage for it but it doesn’t mention the package name. 
how do I install Data.HashTable?

Comment: Try installing [`hashtables`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables) first.

Comment: @Alec It looks like that's installed to me; the error says, in part, "Perhaps you meant... Data.HashTable.IO (... hashtables->1.2.1.0...)".

Comment: Where is the documentation on Hackage? It should be pretty trivial to discover the right package name and version bounds given that.

Comment: [link]http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.1.0/docs/Data-HashTable.html at least the name matches. I did cabal install base and it said, everything’s installed already.

Comment: @Alec that is a different package then the one OP is looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Data.Hashtable` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.0/docs/Data-HashTable.html) was deprecated in `base 4.6` and removed in `base 4.7`. [`base` is a core library](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package). Each version of `ghc` is package with specific version of `base`, so if you wanted to use an older version of `base`, you would have to use an older `ghc`. The last version of `ghc` packaged with `base 4.6` was `ghc 7.6`.

If you need a map, there are better alternatives: `Data.Map` and `Data.IntMap` are ordered map. `Data.HashMap` is a immutable unordered map. `Data.HashTable` and `Data.Judy` are mutable unordered maps.